# SKShader performance slowdown

Tags: performance, opengl-es, sprite-kit, shader, ios8

I need to implement a custom shader node using SpriteKit. 
In simulator everything is ok. On a device (iPad 3rd gen) shader animation is smooth just for first ~30 seconds, after that shader's fps are gradually falling down until it looks like a slideshow (1 fps or even less)

It is worth noting, that SpriteKit shows 60 fps, so does Xcode. 
CPU is ~75% busy, but shader itself shows ~1fps.

I own only 3rd generation iPad and I currently don't have an opportunity to test it on other devices
Shader code is taken from wwdc session, but the issue is reproduced with any animated shaders I've tried.

Shader itself:

```
void main(void)
{
    float currTime = u_time;

    vec2 uv = v_tex_coord;
    vec2 circleCenter = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    vec3 circleColor = vec3(0.8, 0.5, 0.7);
    vec3 posColor = vec3(uv, 0.5+0.5 * sin(currTime)) * circleColor;

    float illu = pow(1. - distance(uv, circleCenter), 4.) * 1.2;
    illu *= (2. + abs(0.4 + cos(currTime * -20. + 50. * distance(uv, circleCenter))/1.5));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(posColor * illu * 2.0, illu * 2.0);
}
```

GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addChild(shaderSprite(view.center))
    }

    func shaderSprite(position: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "dummy"), color: nil, size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
        sprite.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "wwdc")
        sprite.position = position
        return sprite
    }
}
```

Result in simulator or first ~30 seconds on iPad3:

[image]

Result on iPad3 after ~2 minutes:

[image]

Please point my mistake or just build the project on any other device to check if it's a device-specific issue. Thanks in advance.

Test project: https://github.com/alexburtnik/SKShaderTest

Comment: If the performance decreases over time, the resources are not being managed properly.  This happens a lot when people spawn sprites but never remove them when they go off screen

Comment: You're right, but it is not the case. There are no other nodes in the scene at all.

Comment: I have tested it on an iPad Air and it work's flawlessly after several minutes. On an iPad 3, yes, after a minuto or so it starts slowing down and gets worse every minute. Same happens on an iPod Touch 5th :)

Comment: Willhem, thanks a lot for your reply. You saved some hair on my head :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the *u_time* uniform, I got around it by adding my own uniform float and using it instead of using *u_time*

Shader

```
void main(void)
     {
        float currTime = myUniform;
        ...
    }
```

Update

```
 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        let shadedNode = self.childNodeWithName("shadedNode") as SKSpriteNode
        let uniform = shadedNode.shader!.uniformNamed("myUniform")
        uniform!.floatValue = Float(currentTime)
    }
```

Comment: can you please further explain how to implement your solution? when i added a float uniform to the shader and tried to update the value like you suggested, the effect was frozen and i guess it didnt update the time well.

Comment: @Zephyer I've been hitting exactly this problem too. Gelan's answer worked for me. In your shader, you must assign your uniform to a variable. This line is super important `float currTime = myUniform;`

Comment: @razorhead - thanks for the comment! can you please post a code sample using that? what i did was - 
1. add new SKUniform to the shader of type float
2. assign it in the shader (like Gelan said)
3. updated in the update func (like Gelan said)

i think the mistake could be at the first step - what is "myUniform"? did i add it correctly?

edit - what i mean is - what is "myUniform"? just a totally new uniform to add?

Comment: edit2 - the animation does not occur, its just 'stuck'. as if the new time variable doesnt get updated. dont know how to fix this...

Comment: Oh my god. seems that really just using the uniform is not enough. it must be assigned explicitly to a variable. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Gelan Almagro's answer above works perfectly. I'm adding the Objective-C code for the `update:` method.

```
SKSpriteNode *shadedNode = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"shadedNode"];
SKUniform *uniform = [shadedNode.shader uniformNamed:@"myUniform"];
uniform.floatValue = (float)currentTime;
```