# Why is SpriteKit not updating the shader’s uniforms?

Tags: sprite-kit, shader

I added two shaders to my project, one is the same shader from the WWDC 2014 example, and the other has the same code but adding a custom uniform. The problem is that the sprite with the custom uniform is rendered static when the app is running, and with black color on SpriteKit editor in Xcode.

[image]

The shader with the custom uniform is below, `u_speed` is used to control how fast the waves move.

```
void main()
{
    float currTime = u_time * u_speed;

    vec2 uv = v_tex_coord;
    vec2 circleCenter = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    vec3 circleColor = vec3(0.8, 0.5, 0.7);
    vec3 posColor = vec3(uv, 0.5 + 0.5 * sin(currTime)) * circleColor;

    float illu = pow(1. - distance(uv, circleCenter), 4.) * 1.2;
    illu *= (2. + abs(0.4 + cos(currTime * -20. + 50. * distance(uv, circleCenter)) / 1.5));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(posColor * illu * 2., illu * 2.) * v_color_mix.a;
}
```

[This](https://github.com/rraallvv/SpriteKit-shader-custom-uniform/archive/master.zip) is a project I’ve put together with just the shaders and the two sprites showing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your code. There seems to be a bug in how GameScene.sks passes your custom shader uniform into the shader which is causing it to be 0, and the animation to freeze.

If you initialize everything in code rather than in the UI Builder, it works fine. Paste this into your `didMoveToView:` to see what I mean.

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
[self addChild:sprite];
SKShader* spin2x = [SKShader shaderWithFileNamed:@"Shader2"];

spin2x.uniforms = @[
                         [SKUniform uniformWithName:@"u_speed" float:(2.0)],
                         ];
sprite.shader = spin2x;
```

Comment: I found another thread that mentions a similar issue and explains the problem. You cannot use the passed uniforms directly within the shader, you have to first assign them to a variable. Within your uniform, simply adding: float userSpeed = u_speed; and then multiply u_time by userSpeed rather than u_speed. This should make it work with your Interface Builder defined uniform. The thread that has some discussion on this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824414/skshader-performance-slowdown/31196711#31196711

Comment: I think this is the same issue that rraallvv is working around below, getting at the actual uniform value that you're passing in.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like the code below in `didMoveToView:` did the trick, somehow the uniforms are there but are not read by the shader, this "refreshing" of the values did make it work normally.

```
for (SKSpriteNode *sprite in self.children) {
    if ([sprite isKindOfClass:[SKSpriteNode class]]) {
        for (SKUniform *uniform in sprite.shader.uniforms) {
            if (uniform.uniformType == SKUniformTypeFloat) {
                uniform.floatValue = uniform.floatValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want dynamic updating for the uniform it often needs to be updated more than in just didMoveToView. After doing this in the update function I was able to get updates to the shader. It's a shame that it seems like we can't pass a variable by reference to the uniform, but all are passed by value instead.